# Add URI to variable with URIs in Virtuoso and SPARQL

Tags: rdf, sparql, virtuoso

I want to add new uri (as string) to variable that allready have some uris using sparql Virtuoso 7.1. This is my sparql.

```
SELECT ?newURIs WHERE {
 ?newURIs rdf:type res:myClass .
 BIND(URI("http://www.mypage.com/property#myProperty") AS ?newURIs) .
}
```

As I get it, it should add to the list that uri in "...", but it doesn't. 
Response is "Virtuoso 37000 Error SP031: SPARQL compiler: Internal error: Built-in function is not implemented"

i tried:

```
BIND(IRI("...") AS ?newURIs)
```

and then i get results from first row (items from myClass) but my new uri is not there...
Same situation with:

```
BIND("..." AS ?newURIs)
```

and with:

```
BIND(<...> AS ?newURIs)
```

What am i doing wrong? How can i add new URI from string to list of uris in variable?

thnx

Comment: Your question is somewhat unclear, it would be helpful if you provided an example of the results you received and the results you were expecting.  You can use the `edit` button under your question to add additional details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well for a start your query is actually illegal in SPARQL, you can't use `BIND` to assign to an already in-scope variable so your query should be rejected as illegal SPARQL.  This may be what Virtuoso is doing though the error message you got was clearly unhelpful

What you are actually trying to do is a little unclear, from your description it sounds like you have a selection of possible values that you want to use for `?newURIs` in which case the [`VALUES` clause](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#inline-data) would be the appropriate way to do this e.g.

```
SELECT *
WHERE
{
  VALUES ?newURIs
  {
     <http://www.mypage.com/property#myProperty>
     # Other values go here
  }
  ?newURIs rdf:type res:myClass .
}
```

Note however that this will only find matches of your triple pattern where the value of `?newURIs` has one of the values given in your `VALUES` clause which may not actually be what you want.

Comment: Hm, well I have a php script that connects to virtuoso. In that php script I have some URIs. Now I would like to put them in one SPARQL variable (like ?newURIs). That URIs allready exists in database so i could probably use your code like, get all URIs and filter with VALUES only some that I need, but i tried to find out is there some other way to pass my URIs from php query to variable in sparql, so i don't need to filter them from all in db?

Comment: Are you essentially asking for how to do [Prepared Statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement)?

Comment: Oh, i did it with your way with VALUES somehow! :) but I guess Virtuoso has some bug that i can not put multiple values, only one dimensional. :p   
thnx anyway!

Comment: I did it by echoing rows with URIs that i want in variable... Virtuoso i guess has bug that i can only put one variable like error is on:
VALUES (?a ?b ?c)
{
  (1 2 4)
  (2 3 4)
}
couse variables ?b and ?c stays empty